# Property 'navigation' does not exists on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am completely new to react native.

I have the following components:

Playlists:

```
export default class Playlists extends Component {
  playlists = [
    ...
  ];

  render() {
    const {navigation} = this.props.navigation;

    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.playlists}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.item}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('PlaylistDetails', item)}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item.name}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Details View of a Playlist:

```
export default class PlaylistDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    const {navigation} = this.props.navigation;
    var songs: Song[] = navigation.getParam('songs');

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{navigation.getParam('name')}</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={songs}
          renderItem={({item: song}) => <Text>{song.title}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And for navigation:

```
const screens = {
  Playlists: {
    screen: Playlists,
  },
  PlaylistDetails: {
    screen: PlaylistDetails,
  },
};

const stack = createStackNavigator(screens);

export default createAppContainer(stack);
```

But at `const { navigation } = this.props.navigation;` I get an error `Property 'navigation' does not exist on type ...`.

I have tried adding the following code:

```
interface Props {
    navigation: any
}
```

and then adding this:

```
export default class PlaylistDetails extends Component<Props> {
    ...
}
```

This removes the errors, but when I run the application, I get the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')`.

I am totally new to react native and don't know how to solve that. I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Yes, I used to code in Java, so Javascript makes me crazy sometimes at the moment. Idk why, but with typescript it is a little bit easier for me.

Comment: Yes, in my opinion, TypeScript is easier to pickup if you have a background in static typed programming languages such as Java :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is fine, and you are defining the right interface.

However, you should be spreading the props, rather than going 1 level deep and spreading the `navigation` property within the props object.

This is how it should be like:

```
export default class PlaylistDetails extends Component<Props> {
  render() {

    // edit this: 
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    var songs: Song[] = navigation.getParam('songs');

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{navigation.getParam('name')}</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={songs}
          renderItem={({item: song}) => <Text>{song.title}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```